# INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER

Tags: apex, trigger, failing-tests

I'm getting an error INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user, and I have been doing a lot of research and the cause that I have found for this is its attempting to assign a my lead to inactive user.  So I understand that part I think the issue is now I don't actually know how to fix it, I didn't write this trigger/test class and I'm not sure how to go forward.

Do I need to create a new Test User?  I've never worked on the Lead object before..

Edit**
I added IsActive = True the trigger user query, no luck.

Edit**
I just went talking to anyone that might have an idea about UserTypes, and they have no idea what UserType = 'PowerPartner' is.  So I changed it to a different UserType.. didn't work

Edit** 
I'm nuking this trigger, I have to re write it..

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class PartnerLeadShare_test {
static testMethod void myUnitTest1() {
List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
List<LeadShare> leadShareList = new list<LeadShare>(); 

Lead ld = new Lead();
ld.lastName = 'Tester';//=/
ld.Company = 'MyCompany';
ld.Status = 'Open';
ld.Program_EAU__c ='11';
insert ld;
system.debug('ld****' +ld);

GroupMember groupMemberStore = [select GroupId,UserOrGroupId from GroupMember limit 1];

LeadShare ls = new LeadShare(); 
ls.LeadId = ld.id;
ls.UserOrGroupId = groupMemberStore.UserOrGroupId ;
ls.LeadAccessLevel = 'Edit';
leadShareList.add(ls);

 if(leadShareList.size()>0){
    system.debug('INSIDE LEADSHARE LIST.');
     insert leadShareList;
 }
 }
}
```

Don't know this will help but here is my trigger..

```
trigger PartnerLeadShare on Lead (after insert,after update) {

Map<id,User>PartnerUsermap = new Map<id,user>([select id,UserType from user where      UserType = 'PowerPartner' and IsActive = True] );   
List<GroupMember>GroupMemberList = new List<GroupMember>([select GroupId,UserOrGroupId   from GroupMember]); 

System.debug('PartnerUsermap ===  '  +PartnerUsermap);
System.debug('GroupMemberList    '+GroupMemberList );

List<LeadShare> leadShareList = new list<LeadShare>(); 

 if(!PartnerUsermap.isEmpty()){
for(Lead ld: trigger.new){ 
    for(GroupMember grpmem : GroupMemberList){
        if(grpmem.UserOrGroupId == ld.CreatedById){  
            LeadShare ldShare = new LeadShare (LeadId = ld.id,UserOrGroupId = grpmem.GroupId,LeadAccessLevel = 'Edit'); 
            leadShareList.add(ldShare );
        }
    }
}
}
if(!leadShareList.isEmpty()){
Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(leadShareList,false);           
Integer i=0;
for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
    if(!sr.isSuccess()){
    Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0]; 
            if(!(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  
                                           &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))){

                trigger.newMap.get(leadShareList[i].LeadId).
                  addError(
                   'Unable to grant sharing access due to following exception: '
                   + err.getMessage());
            }
    }
   i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance you have an inactive User in some of your groups?  Try removing them from those groups and see if you still get the issue.

Comment: I think I may of figured it out.  I'm testing it right now, but I just fed in a hard coded value in the test class.  I just want to see if we even need it so I will be deactivating it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment just yet so I'm writing this as an answer. Are you saying that this error only happens when the test is run?

Re: Your question about 'PowerPartner'. You can find the different user types here: [Salesforce User Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/what-are-the-possible-options-for-usertype)

Comment: It breaks when I run the test class. I'm going to update my question

Comment: It's also weird that it works on a different dev client ..

Comment: When is it working? Also, can you confirm that the trigger is working correctly when not being run by the test code?

Comment: Oh good idea, So now that I'm really looking into the trigger, it was really poorly written.  I'll test that