# How to guard a FeedItem insert when code is executing in a Force.com Site?

Tags: chatter, force.com-sites, permissions, describesobject

I have some code that is used both through a normally licensed user and through a "Site Guest User" for a public [Force.com Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites). I am aware that for the latter type of User Chatter capabilities are not supported.

My first go at adding a guard (to not insert a FeedItem and so avoid any error) was get the describe information for `FeedItem` and check the [isCreateable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_isCreateable) but that returns true:

> describe=Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[getKeyPrefix=0D5;getLabel=Feed Item;getLabelPlural=Feed Items;getName=FeedItem;isAccessible=true;isCreateable=true;isCustom=false;isCustomSetting=false;isDeletable=true;isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;isFeedEnabled=false;isMergeable=false;isQueryable=true;isSearchable=true;isUndeletable=false;isUpdateable=false;]

with the above produced by this test code when run through a Force.com Site:

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public PageReference doit() {
        System.debug('describe=' + FeedItem.SobjectType.getDescribe());
        System.debug('user=' + UserInfo.getUserType());
        insert new FeedItem(
                        Type = 'LinkPost',
                        Title = 'Test title',
                        ParentId = 'a0N900000098HOdEAM',
                        LinkUrl = 'http://www.google.com',
                        Body = 'Test body'
                        );
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I am looking for an alternative technique other than catching the DmlException:

> DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Entity is read-only: FeedItem:
>   []

I note that the `UserInfo.getUserType()` returns "Guest" instead of "Standard" when access is through a Force.com Site. Is that the best thing to use? In my org I see 8 possible values; are these documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have it correct, I think your best bet is to use the UserInfo class. The getUserType() function that you called out is likely easiest. Alternatively, you could use getProfileId() to check to make sure you don't have the guest profile.

Also, there is a good overview of user types on this other Stack Exchange post: [What are the possible options for UserType?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/what-are-the-possible-options-for-usertype)