# soql for total license used in SFDC

Tags: apex, soql, userlicense

I am looking for soql which could fetch me all the license used for all inactive and active users in one shot. similar to displaying company license information in native SFDC environment.

I am working on displaying the license information on VF such that i can have my own custom activation and deactivation of users in organization.

Any light on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(id), profile.usertype, isactive 
from user 
group by profile.usertype, isactive 
order by profile.usertype, isactive
```

Look here for a breakdown of how to interpret the different user types: [What are the possible options for UserType?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/what-are-the-possible-options-for-usertype)

Answer (score 0):

force query `select id, name, isactive, profile.userlicense.name from user`

Will give you the users and their license type.