# how to hide a link from sites?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, commandlink

I have `Visualforce Page` with three `<apex:commandLinnk>` tags (e.g. "New Record", "Edit Record", and"Change Record"). The first link shouldn't be displayed in Sites, but only in `Visualforce Pages`.

If I view this `Visualforce Page` in a Force.com Site, I should only see the "Edit Record" and "Change Record" links. Is it possible? **How can I set a visibility condition based on whether or not the page is being displayed in a Force.com Site?**

```
<div id="firstBlock" class="one element-animation-slide">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages><br/><br/>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!newShow}" id="authClick" value="New Record" style="text-decoration: none;" styleClass="slideUp element-animation" rerender="optionPanel, newCRpanel, wholePanel"/><br/><br/><br/>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!editShow}" id="createClick" value="Edit Record" style="text-decoration: none;" styleClass="slideUp element-animation" rerender="optionPanel, newCRpanel, wholePanel"/><br/><br/><br/>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!changeshow}" value="Change Record" style="text-decoration: none;" styleClass="slideUp element-animation" rerender="optionPanel, editCRpanel, wholePanel"/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site class has a method `getSiteTypeLabel()` which basically gives your sites name(label). if its not invoked from a site this method returns null.

Have a boolean in your controller 'showNewButton' and set its value in the constructor of the VF page class.
If `site.getSiteTypeLabel() != null` set it to false. else set it to true

in your VF page add a rendered condition to the commandlink based on this condition

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!newShow}" id="authClick" value="New Record" style="text-decoration: none;" styleClass="slideUp element-animation" rerender="optionPanel, newCRpanel, wholePanel" rendered="{!showNewButton}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check which type of user is logged in currently. Because when user will be on a site he will be either a guest user or community licensed user.

So what can you do is check the **UserType** in **rendered** attribute.

```
rendered="{!$User.userType = 'Guest'}"
```

There are various possible values of **userType** available at below link, you can refer.

[Various values of UserType](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249045&type=1)

You can also refer to a similar thread available:

[Similar Thread Here - Click on it.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/what-are-the-possible-options-for-usertype)