# Is it possible to have a full list of the values the API returns for User Type?

Tags: api, user-management

I'm reading this document to figure out which User information I can get from the API:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

And there are some User Types mentioned, however when I call the endpoint `/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+UserType+from+User`, I get some types that are not mentioned in the document, such as `AutomateProcess` or `CloudIntegrationUser`.

Is it possible to find a complete list of these User Types? I'm not a Salesforce user and I'm only writing an API integration so I'm not sure if these types are editable by the user. If that's not the case, where would I find an exhaustive list of User Types?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: what will your integration do? It's likely you'll want to filter that query of yours to pull internal users only (UserType = Standard) or some other criteria that should exclude those not listed in the docs. For example, `AutomateProcess` refers to [Automated users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339878&type=1&mode=1) Salesforce reserves which I can't imagine providing value to your integration. You can see some others not listed in the docs in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/what-are-the-possible-options-for-usertype)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that thread but being that most of the answers are at least seven or eight years old, I was hoping to find an authoritative documentation page that I could refer to, not just guesses or values that other users had figured out by experimenting with the API.